# How to make excel sheet in java

Tags: java, excel, cmd

I want to make java application to

1. read from list of files saved in folder.
2. send the name for every file to command line.
3. take the output from cmd and save it in arraylist
4. make hash map to save all arraylists in it for example hash map(key,value)
5. write excel sheet to write all permissions for every file in folder

**The problem is** only one record appear in excel sheet and hash map save only the last file why???any one help me to continue this code ?
write all records in excel sheet I have 12 files

My code:

```
public class CreateExcellSheet {
public  String line;
public Map < String, Object[] > appinfo = new TreeMap < String, Object[] >();
public int counter=0;
public ArrayList<String> permissions=new ArrayList<String>();
public Set<String> permissionsSet=new HashSet<String>();
public ArrayList<String> AppPermissions=new ArrayList<String>();
public String AppName;
public HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>> singleAppPermissions=new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>>(); 
public int key=0;
public CreateExcellSheet() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CreateExcellSheet createExcelSheet=new CreateExcellSheet();
    final File folder = new File("GooglePlaySamples");


     for ( File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {

         createExcelSheet.AppPermissions.clear();

                createExcelSheet.AppName = fileEntry.getName();
                 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "aapt d permissions GooglePlaySamples/"+createExcelSheet.AppName);
                builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
                Process p = builder.start();
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
               createExcelSheet.key++;
                while (true) {
                    createExcelSheet.line = r.readLine();
                    if (createExcelSheet.line == null) { break; }
                    else if (createExcelSheet.line.startsWith("package:")){continue;}
                    else if(createExcelSheet.line.startsWith("W/asset")){continue;}
                   else if(createExcelSheet.line.startsWith("ERROR")){continue;}
                   // System.out.println(createExcelSheet.line);
                   createExcelSheet.permissions.add(createExcelSheet.line);
                 createExcelSheet.AppPermissions.add(createExcelSheet.line);
                createExcelSheet.counter++;           
                }
               createExcelSheet.singleAppPermissions.put(createExcelSheet.key, createExcelSheet.AppPermissions);                 

        }
     System.out.println(createExcelSheet.key+""+createExcelSheet.singleAppPermissions.get(9));

    createExcelSheet.permissionsSet.addAll(createExcelSheet.permissions);
    createExcelSheet.permissions.clear();
    createExcelSheet.permissions.addAll(createExcelSheet.permissionsSet);

    //Create blank workbook
              XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
      //Create a blank sheet
      XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet(" Employee Info ");

      //Create row object
      for (int i=0;i<createExcelSheet.permissions.size();i++){  
          createExcelSheet.appinfo.put( "1",new Object[] {createExcelSheet.permissions.get(i)});
      }
      XSSFRow row,newrow;
      //Iterate over data and write to sheet
      Set < String > keyid = createExcelSheet.appinfo.keySet();
      int rowid = 0;
      newrow = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);
      for (String key : keyid)
      {
         row = spreadsheet.createRow(0);
         Object [] objectArr = createExcelSheet.appinfo.get(key);
         for (Object obj : objectArr)
         {
           // Cell cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
            for (int i=0;i<createExcelSheet.permissions.size();i++){
            row.createCell(i).setCellValue(createExcelSheet.permissions.get(i));
            }              
         }

            for (Object obj : objectArr)
            {
                 newrow=spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);                              
                 for(int i=0;i<createExcelSheet.permissions.size();i++){
                     for(int j=0;j<createExcelSheet.AppPermissions.size();j++){
                 if(createExcelSheet.permissions.get(i).equals(createExcelSheet.AppPermissions.get(j))){
                     //System.out.println(createExcelSheet.permissions.get(i));
                    newrow.createCell(i).setCellValue(1);

            }

         }
             }

      //Write the workbook in file system
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( new File("Writesheet.xlsx"));
      workbook.write(out);
      out.close();

      System.out.println(  "Writesheet.xlsx written successfully" );

}   
      }}}
```

Comment: Weird edit criss-cross, sorry (I did remove "enter code here" and somehow, this cancelled OP edit :/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use the same key (i.e. "1") for all your `HashMap` entries.

You probably want:

```
for (int i=0;i<createExcelSheet.permissions.size();i++){  
    createExcelSheet.appinfo.put("" + (i+1),new Object[] {createExcelSheet.permissions.get(i)});
}
```

Because when you do:

```
map.put("1", someObject);
map.put("1", anotherObject);
```

the entry with key "1" is overwritten

Comment: how can I use the same key please give me details

Comment: it increases every time createExcelSheet.key++;

Comment: the problem in this line: createExcelSheet.singleAppPermissions.put(createExcelSheet.key, createExcelSheet.AppPermissions);it gives me when i write: System.out.println(createExcelSheet.key+""+createExcelSheet.singleAppPermissions.get(any number from 1 to 12));the same result for the last file